# Firefox vim mode, can't switch to normal mode in style editor

Tags: vim, codemirror, firefox-developer-tools

When I use vim mode in firefox dev tools settings, <kbd>Esc</kbd> trigger split console in the style editor. So, I can't leave insert mode. In the scratchpad <kbd>Esc</kbd> works well tho, but in the style editor there is always split console. Is there a way to redefine split console to another key, or what will be even better to redefine <kbd>Esc</kbd> for vim mode?

Answer (score 6):

You can use Ctrl-C for this purpose.

Comment:  Thank you! This works on hackmd and codewars too

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1173056).  Thanks for pointing it out!  CC your email address on the bug to get emails pertaining to resolution and updates.

Comment: The bug in the answer got marked as a duplicate of [bug 972534](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=972534).